# PHP session_start() and session_abort() behavior looks somewhat unexpected

Tags: php, session, session-variables

The following PHP code behaves unexpected to some extent. Can you please explain it?

```
<?php
  session_start();
  //$_SESSION["variable"] = 55;
  
  $_SESSION["variable"]++;
  var_dump($_SESSION);
  //session_abort();
?>
```

When I de-comment //session_abort(), it still increments the session variable on the first page refresh but stops on subsequent ones. The session variable is still accessible. I would expect the session starts on each refresh, variable gets incremented and then session aborts. If the session variable is still available, why isn't incrementing it working?

Comment: This seems inline with [the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-abort.php) which state "session_abort() finishes session without saving data. Thus the original values in session data are kept."